# C# asp.net insert record to sharepoint online list with field type "Person or Group"

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-online

I would like to insert record to sharepoint online list using C# asp.net. The list contains two columns Title, User with Type "Single line of text", "Person or Group" respectively. For Column Title , I can assign the value to the ListItem directly. However, for Column User, I should assign with type FieldUserValue. I would like to know how can I get the FieldUserValue from sharepoint site using the email address or the other lookup value.

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(url);
ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, Password);
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("List1");
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem items = list.AddItem(new ListItemCreationInformation());
items["Title"] = InsertTitle.Text;
items["User"] = ??? (FieldUserValue); 
items.Update();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```